# Extraneous Tags from Webscraping for Subheaders

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the Wikipedia page "Genome." I want to scrape only the subheaders like "Origin of the Term", "Sequencing and Mapping", "Viral Genomes", "Prokaryotic Genomes," "Eukaryotic Genomes", including the sub-sub headers under that, Genome Size, etc., etc. . To do that I wrote the following code to do it:

```
    def filter_headers(self, web_soup):
        # Grabs the headers from the web page
        """
        :param web_soup: the raw web soup from the webpage
        :return: header_soup: the headers in text form
        """
        # TO DO: how to separate out just the main body content while including the
        # title header
        # Find all tags with a pattern like h1,h2,h3,h4...
        headers = read_page_soup.find_all(re.compile(r'h\d+'))

        return headers
```

The problem is no matter how specific I filter out my tags, I still get the same results with extraneous headers from the navigation menu like [Personal tools, Namespaces, Variants, Views...Tools,Print/Export, In Other Projects, Languages]. For example, I tried this first:

```
soup = read_page_soup.find(re.compile(r'h\d+'), {'class': 'mw-body-content'})
    results = sr.filter_headers(soup)
    for result in results:
        print(result.text)
```

Then I tried this, filtering through the mw-parser-output class, like this:

```
soup = read_page_soup.find(re.compile(r'h\d+'), {'class': 'mw-parser-content'})
    results = sr.filter_headers(soup)
    for result in results:
        print(result.text)
```

I don't understand this. The divs that I'm hovering over do not even highlight the wikipedia sidebar when I hover over them. I want to be able to find a solution that works for many wikipedia pages, so that I can scrape them all with similar results. Then in the future I'm hoping to extend this to other web pages like Ars Technica. So if anyone can give any fair warnings as well, about I guess using this approach for some rudimentary web crawling. If I'm out of my depth to try this case by case basis for some rudimentary web crawling without a web crawling app, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a header tag, but both classes you're describing are `divs`. The Wikipedia pages I have tested usually have three `mw-body-content` classes (all of them are `div`, the same happens to the single `mw-parser-output` class):

```html
<div id="siteNotice" class="mw-body-content">
<div class="mw-indicators mw-body-content">
<div id="bodyContent" class="mw-body-content">
```

To get multiple page header titles you can use the `mw-body-content` class you already have, but switch to `find_all` and select the third item. From that point on, the logic used inside the `filter_headers` with `find_all` and the regex for the `header` seems to produce the expected result.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

source = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genome').text
read_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

def filter_headers(web_soup):
    headers = web_soup.find_all(re.compile(r'h\d+'))
    return headers

soup = read_page_soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'mw-body-content'})[2]
results = filter_headers(soup)
for result in results:
    hN = int(result.name[1:])*3-3
    print(f"{result.name} {'-'*hN} {result.text}")
```

Output

```
h2 --- Contents
h2 --- Origin of term[edit]
h2 --- Sequencing and mapping[edit]
h2 --- Viral genomes[edit]
h2 --- Prokaryotic genomes[edit]
h2 --- Eukaryotic genomes[edit]
h3 ------ Coding sequences[edit]
h3 ------ Noncoding sequences[edit]
h4 --------- Tandem repeats[edit]
h4 --------- Transposable elements[edit]
h5 ------------ Retrotransposons[edit]
h5 ------------ DNA transposons[edit]
h2 --- Genome size[edit]
h3 ------ Genome size due to transposable elements[edit]
...
...
```

Comment: I think this worked when I changed my parser from html to lxml and get from requests instead of something more specialized like urlopen from requests

Comment: Also, do you think this sort of piecemeal approach to web scraping would work okay for basic web crawling?

Comment: @pancham2016 For basic web crawling I think this approach is ok. You just have to pay attention for sites that `dynamically` load the data using `javascript`. In this context you would've to use something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just grab that info from the `li` elements within the list of contents `#toc li`? There are two child `spans`, per `li`, containing the bullet numbering and name:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genome')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
contents = [i.select_one('.tocnumber').text + ' ' + i.select_one('.toctext').text  for i in soup.select('#toc li')]
```